# Inserting text after a certain image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, loops

In one function I have a loop that creates 10 images using the createElement();. In the other function I have another loop that contains info that I need to add text after each picture but my code adds it at the end of all 10 pictures I need them to be after every corresponding picture.
This is the function that displays the text:

```
function displayAlbum(json){
  for (var x = 0; x<json.length;x++){
  var span1 = document.createElement("span");

  span1.innerText = json[x].album;
  console.log(json[x].album);
  var display = document.getElementById("results");
  display.appendChild(span1);
  }
}
```

I cant individually set the id of each image because i created them in js. Thanks for the help in advance and no jquery please

```
  for (var x = 0; x<json.length;x++){
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.id = "picture";
  image.width = 100;
  image.height = 100;
  image.src = json[x].cover;
  var display = document.getElementById("results");
  display.appendChild(image);

  var a = document.getElementById("artist");
  var y = document.getElementById("year");
  var artist = document.getElementById("artist").selectedIndex;//index of value of the switch statement
  var year = document.getElementById("year").selectedIndex;//index of value of the switch statement
  var realYear = y[year].text;//Value of the selected text
  var realArtist = a[artist].text;//Value of the selected text
  var display = document.getElementById("Results");
  }
```

This is my second loop. I want displayalbum to appear after every picture. I cannot combine them because of other complications in the code

Comment: Why don't you just have the 2 loops rolled into 1 loop? Also, please show both loops that you have now.

Comment: So why can't you roll the 2 loops into 1?

Comment: I have if statements that call each function and I give them a value but the value changes when I call them all one after the other. So I have to spread them out and load the first function, call the second one, and assigns the same variable to a different value

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to get each image on the screen without id's because I added the images using create element in a loop and display text corresponding to each image after every image

Comment: I figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop where you are creating images, give a unique id to image like `image.id = "picture" + x;`

Then change displayAlbum() function to use corresponding image to place the span tag.

```
function displayAlbum(json){
  for (var x = 0; x<json.length;x++){
    var span1 = document.createElement("span");
    span1.innerText = json[x].album;
    console.log(json[x].album);

    var display = document.getElementById("results");
    var img = document.getElementById("picture" + x); // use unique id of img to access it
    if(img.nextSibling) { // if img is not the last node in 'results'
      display.insertBefore(span1, img.nextSibling);
    } else { // if img is the last node in 'results'
      display.appendChild(span1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like that: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xv7WI0oUC4u5b7i1iHEx?p=preview)

```
function displayAlbum(){
  for (var x = 0; x < 10 ; x++){ // change to json.length
  var span1 = document.createElement("span");

  span1.innerText = 'json[x].album';
  span1.id = 'span'+x;

  var display = document.getElementById("results");
  display.appendChild(span1);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal with single loop and using Figure and FigCaption element , specifically created for this kind of display image with its description

```js
var json = [{cover:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Internet2.jpg/440px-Internet2.jpg", album:"test1"},{cover:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Internet2.jpg/440px-Internet2.jpg", album:"test2"}];



 for (var x = 0; x<json.length;x++){
   
  var fig = document.createElement("figure");
  var figCap = document.createElement("figcaption");
  figCap.innerText = json[x].album;
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.id = "picture";
  image.width = 100;
  image.height = 100;
  image.src = json[x].cover;
  var display = document.getElementById("results");
  fig.appendChild(image);
  fig.appendChild(figCap);
  display.appendChild(fig);

  }
```

```html
<div id="results">
  </div>
```